# What is the security of multiple encryption using Even–Mansour scheme (XEX)?

Tags: block-cipher, xor, multiple-encryption, meet-in-the-middle-attack

As I know, [the best attack on single or double Even-Mansour scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/541) is N/2, being N the key size (or size of one of the two keys used).

I know that encrypting two times using this scheme is susceptible to [Meet-in-the middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack), but if encrypting three or more times, what security in bit I will get for each layer added?

I'm asking this because XORs will be applied multiple times in the encipherment, maybe the security estimation may diverge from a "normal" block cipher like AES used multiple times; and I want to create a simple block cipher for encrypting my stuff with multiple layers of XORs and pseudo-random permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better known as iterated Even-mansour or key-alternating cipher. From [Theorem 1 of Hoang-Tessaro](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/578) we have
$$
\mathrm{Adv}^{\pm\mathrm{prp}}_{\mathrm{KAC}[\pi,t]} \le \frac{4^tqp_1\cdots p_t}{2^{nt}}\,,
$$
for $t$ iterations of Even-Mansour on an $n$-bit permutation, where $q$ are the online queries, and $p_i$ are the offline queries to each individual permutation. This roughly translates to security up to $O(2^{nt/(t+1)})$ queries.

But the above is for **independent** permutations at each iteration, which is the easier to analyze case. In reality you're gonna use the same permutation for each iteration, which is more complicated to analyze. [Chen et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/443) do this analsis for the 2-iteration case and show that it still reaches security up to $O(2^{2n/3})$ queries. [Wu et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1073) did the same for the 3-iteration, showing it is secure up to $O(2^{3n/4})$ queries.